# how to extract the whole word in the line when there is a match of my substring found perl regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, strawberry-perl

I am parsing multiple log files from perl(Windows) generated on different dates.
each file has only one line, which contains a pattern as below:

**notepad/*version_number***

- entry "notepad" is constant
- version_number varies for each file
- both are always separated by /

In my current line read from the log file, if the string notepad is present, I want to extract **notepad/*version_number*** into a variable (including **/**)

Can someone please help me out with this. Thank you.

```
foreach $file (@file_names)
{
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
    or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";

    while (my $row = <$fh>)
    {
        if($row =~  "notepad")
        {
            #here I want to extract the part of the line which I have highligted above(notepad/*version_number) into a variable.
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code snippet from my script. Hope this helps.

**Sample line from log file:**

```
02/13/2014 22:39:51:464227 some_text notepad/v1.10.12 some_text
```

Comment: First step is to write a program and show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible I've oversimplified your task, but I think this is all you would need:

```
foreach $file (@file_names)
{
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
    or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";

    while (my $row = <$fh>)
    {
        my ($result) = $row =~ m|(notepad/v\d+\.\d+\.\d+)|;
        if ($result) {
           # we have a match            
        }
    }
}
```

You already have a regex to find the match -- I wouldn't add a second one; I would just expand it to do the text and capture in one step.  If `$result` is empty, then you pretty much know the match failed.  If it is not, then you have your text.

If the version text is anything other than v*x*.*x*.*x*, then you would of course need to tweak the regex to support the variations.

-- edit, per OP's comment --

"everything from notepad/ until the next immediate whitespace"

```
my ($result) = $row =~ m|(notepad/\S+)|;
```

matches "notepad/" and then all non-whitespace characters.

Comment: I have attempted to put an edit to do what you seek...  try it out and let me know if it's not doing what you think it should be doing.